# Apache: Redirect WWW to naked domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application that was written using Laravel, and it generates dynamic subdomains. Thus, I have a wildcard(`*`) routing mechanism. Due to several complications I'm having with SSL, I need to redirect the `www.example.com` routes to the naked domain (`example.com`), preferrably in the Apache .conf files using RewriteRules.

I've done a few searches and seen a few examples, but most of what I've seen either redirects *all* subdomains to the naked domain (which breaks the subdomain functionality I stated above) or does the reverse of what I'm trying to do (redirects the naked domain to www) which causes a redirect loop in many of my existing routes.

Is this something that can be done using Apache?

**EDIT:**

I think I fixed it. For anyone else having similar problems, I used the following rules in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects any URL that starts with `www` to its naked equivalent, which has the added benefit of stripping `www` from subdomains (so, for example, `www.test.example.com` is redirected to `test.example.com` which is great (although unnecessary) since `www.{subdomain}.example.com` is not a defined route in my app and won't work anyways.

Comment: `http://%1$1` should probably be `http://%1/$1`. Otherwise `www.example.com/directory/` would become `example.comdirectory/`. I'd make the edit myself, but it's only one character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I fixed it. For anyone else having similar problems, I used the following rules in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects any URL that starts with `www` to its naked equivalent, which has the added benefit of stripping `www` from subdomains (so, for example, `www.test.example.com` is redirected to `test.example.com` which is great (although unnecessary) since `www.{subdomain}.example.com` is not a defined route in my app and won't work anyways.

Comment: `http://%1$1` should probably be `http://%1/$1`. Otherwise `www.example.com/directory/` would become `example.comdirectory/`. I'd make the edit myself, but it's only one character.